# pgAdmin3 can't connect properly to Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed `pgadmin3` version `1.10.2`, however when it connects to PostgreSQL server version 9.2, it says:

> Warning:
>
> This version of pgAdmin has only been tested with PostgreSQL version
>   8.4 and below and may not function correctly with this server. Please upgrade pgAdmin.

Then it will throw this error:

> An error has occurred:
>
> ERROR:  column "datconfig" does not exist LINE 1: ...b.dattablespace
>   AS spcoid, spcname, datallowconn, datconfig,...

etc.

Also I am quite stuck with my working version of `pgAdmin3` as I am using Ubuntu Lucid. So is there a work-around for pgAdmin3 to work properly keeping my curent version of pgAdmin3?

Comment: So your question actually is: how to install newer version of pgAdmin3 on Ubuntu? You should ask it there.

Comment: No... i'm not asking that

Comment: My question is, why pgAdmin3 can't properly connect to the DB server

Comment: @xybrek Well, it explains that in the warning. PgAdmin needs to know some details about the server that are version specific. This version of PgAdmin is too old to know about 9.2, so it won't work reliably.

Comment: What kind of operating system is that, that doesn't let you install new versions? Can't you just download the binaries from http://www.pgadmin.org/  and install them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than not using features that cause errors, no, there is no workaround. Since in this case one of the features that causes an error appears to be listing tablespaces during startup, you're out of luck.

Just compile a newer version of PgAdmin-III from sources or use the command-line `psql` client that comes with PostgreSQL 9.2.

PostgreSQL's system catalogs aren't 100% compatible from version to version. That's intentional; if they had to be exactly the same it'd be very hard to make changes and improvements to PostgreSQL. Programs that use the system catalogs should be prepared to require updates when a new PostgreSQL version comes out. Most tools that use the catalogs - like `psql`, PgAdmin-III, `pg_dump`, etc - do so because it's the only way to get detailed information about some of the inner workings of the system. You just need to update them when you update the server.